# Migrate Web Part from one environment to another?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, sharepoint-foundation, deployment

SharePoint Foundation 2010. I have added a very basic web part to my development environment. It is honestly just the Visual Web Part template. I would like to export this web part and import to another environment.

I have tried exporting from the Web Part Gallery as well as from a web part page. I also tried importing from the Web Part Gallery and the page too. I even tried the process through SharePoint Designer. Every time I try this I get the dreaded "Cannot import this web part" message. I have also tried the following.

- Safe Control Entry in web.config
- Managed code assembly (dll) in the GAC

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the exported webpart's xml for any settings that might prevent it from being imported ? Can't you deploy the webpart the same way to this new environment as you did to the first one ?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use PowerShell To Deploy WSP In Farm Solution

```
Add-SPSolution "C:\example.wsp"
```